# Reorder the sequence of records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to rearrange multiple records After deleting multiple records.My code deletes one record and rearrange all records but when i delete multiple records,it cant reshuffle.

This codes works great when we delete one record but not work for multiple records,

```
$sql="delete from $user where id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

$reorder = "update $user set id=id-1 where id > $id";
$catch = mysql_query($reorder,$connection);
```

Comment: your approach is totally wrong, what if `id <= $id`? leave it as is, why you do that?

Comment: this way is dangerous, mysql manual did mention about the danger of this  type of  query

Answer (score 0):

you may need to do a query for for all rows that require reorder, then re-order them by calling the UPDATE statement one at a time, but be careful with the SET id='xx-1' WHERE id='xx'